# 'Easy to be solved' versus 'Easy to solve'

Tags: adjectives, passive-voice, infinitives, auxiliary-verbs

> a) This problem is easy to solve.
>   b) This problem is easy to be solved.

Which sentence is more natural, a) or b)?

Comment: There's another version: This problem is *easily solved*.

Answer (score 3):

a) is very much more natural. Phrases like "easy to", "hard to", "complicated to" nearly always take an active verb (focussing on the person doing it) rather than a passive.

Comment: It's easy **to be taken ** in by a question like this! ;-)

Comment: That idiom "be taken in" barely exists in the active.

Comment: It's easy **to be fooled** by a question like this then?

Comment: I did say "nearly always", not "always".

Comment: I know, hence my fist comment - just a comment  not a criticism ... [hence the smiley and so on and so forth ...]

Answer (score 2):

> a) This problem is easy to solve.
>   b) This problem is easy to be solved. (ungrammatical)

### **Short answer**

Sentence (b) is ungrammatical. We need to use sentence (a) here. If the Subject of the main sentence isn't the word *it*, we can't use passives after the adjective *easy*.

---

### **Full answer**

The adjective *easy* belongs to a family of adjectives often called *TOUGH* adjectives. (The *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* describes them as adjectives which take hollow clauses).

Let's look at the grammatical example:

- This problem is easy to solve.

This sentence has a Subject *this problem*. The verb in the sentence is *BE*. This verb is taking an adjective phrase *easy to solve* as a Complement.

Inside the adjective phrase *easy to solve* there is an infinitival construction *to solve*. This verb phrase is a clause without any overt Subject. Notice that although the verb *solve* is usually transitive, we can't see any Object here.

Adjectives like *easy* often take infinitival clauses like this. If we don't state what the subject of the clause is, then we need to guess what it is from the context. Here we understand that the sentence means:

- This problem is easy **for people** to solve.

But notice that we also understand that the verb *solve* has an Object in this sentence too. When adjectives like *easy* have infinitival clauses like this, the Object of the verb in the infinitival is decided by one of the noun phrases in the main clause. When the verb in the main clause is the verb *BE*, the Object of the infinitival clause is decided by the Subject of the verb *BE*:

- This problem<sub>(i)</sub> is easy for people to solve ____<sub>(i)</sub> .

We understand the sentence like this:

- This problem is easy [ for people to solve <s>this problem</s> ].

**Example (b)**

The Original Poster's example (b) has a big problem. The infinitival clause is in the passive. This means that it has no space for an Object any more. 
The writer of this sentence is trying to use the adjective *easy* like the adjective *keen*. The adjective *keen* is not a tough adjective. When we use adjectives like *keen*, the *Subject* of the infinitival clause is decided by the Subject of *BE*:

- Bob was keen to leave.
- Bob<sub>(i)</sub> was keen [ _____<sub>(i)</sub> to leave ].
- **Bob** was keen [**for Bob** to leave]

Now if the infinitival clause is passive with adjectives like *keen* , there is still a Subject space in the infinitival clause:

- Bob was keen to be elected president.
- Bob<sub>(i)</sub> was keen [ _____<sub>(i)</sub> to be elected president ].
- **Bob** was keen [ **for Bob**  to be elected president ].

However, as we said, *easy* is a tough adjective. It doesn't work like *keen*. The Subject of *BE* cannot control the Subject of the infinitival clause. It must decide the *Object* of the infinitival clause. This is impossible in the Original Poster's example (b), because there is no Object!

Here is what our brains try to do with example (b):

- This problem is easy [ for something to be solved <s>this problem</s> ].

This is completely ungrammatical. When we use tough adjectives like *easy*, the infinitival clause must have a space for an Object after the verb. We can't use passive infinitival clauses after tough adjectives like this.

Answer (score 1):

I must say sometimes it is really difficult to decide whether after a noun an infinitive active or passive is the right thing. In any case I haven't found a rule. I think often both possibilities are good. 
An example from Animal Farm: When there was work to be done the cat could never be found. I'm sure "work to do" is possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

> a) This problem is easy to solve.
>
> b) This problem is easy to be solved.

Sometimes it confuses us. but In my case, I've checked it up like this.

> This problem is easy (for people) to solve.
>
> = It is easy for people to solve this problem.
>
> = It is easy that people solve this problem.

Here, you can see 'People solve this problem. (O)' correct, but 
the below sentence doesn't make sense and is not correct grammantically.

'People is solved this problem.' (X)